# Spring boot Log4j2 log file not appearing in external Tomcat logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, log4j2

I've created spring boot app and logs are appearing fine while using the embedded Tomcat (have to add the catalina.home in JVM). But after deploying the app on external Tomcat, there are not logs as Hello_*.log.
Here's my Log4j config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60" status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">applogs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    %d{dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level]  [%pid] [%t] %c{1.} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <File name="Hello"
            fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/Hello_${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    %d{dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level]  [%pid] [%t] %c{1.} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <File name="Hello-Error"
            fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/Hello_error_${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    %d{dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level]  [%pid] [%t] %c{1.} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" />
        <Logger name="org.springframework.ws.server" level="INFO" />
        <Logger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />
        <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup" level="INFO" />
        <Logger name="com.hello" level="INFO" />
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" />
            <!-- Log all messages to the file Hello_<date>.log -->
            <AppenderRef ref="Hello"  level="INFO"  />
            <!-- Log all messages with a level >= WARNING to the separate file Hello_error_<date>.log -->
            <AppenderRef ref="Hello-Error" level="WARN" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Try setting the `catalina_home` in your environment variables.

Comment: `catalina_home` is already set when Tomcat starts